# Interior of union of complex set is empty

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $X_n=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid\hspace{0.2cm}Re(z)+Im(z)=\frac{1}{n},Re(z)\geq 0, Im(z)\geq 0\}$. I have already prove that $int(X_n)=\emptyset$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n$. Graphically it’s easy to see that $int(X)=\emptyset$, but I don’t know how to prove it.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Given $z\in X$, there is some $n$ with $\text{Re}(x)+\text{Im}(x)=1/n$.  Then for $\epsilon<(1/(n-1))-(1/n)$ we have $z+\epsilon\notin X$ if I'm not mistaken.  So $z\notin X^\circ$.  BTW this has nothing to do with complex analysis, you can remove this tags.

Comment: Each $X_n$ is  nowhere-dense. The Baire Category Theorem implies $\cup_n X_n$ has empty interior.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Awesome! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topologically $Re(z) + Im(z)$ is the same as $f(x,y) = x+y$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is open as it is the composition of open maps. If $ U \subset X$ where U is open then  $ f(U) \subset \{ 1/n  |  n \in \mathbb{N} \} $ where $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. But a countable open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is empty so $U$ is empty and as this holds for all open sets $U$ contained in $X$, the interior of $X$ is empty.

Comment: Thanks for replying!, but I have a question., what is $f$?

Comment: Oh lol f is meant to be x+y sorry

Answer (score 1):

Let $z\in X_m .$  Any open set $U$ containing $z$ covers an open ball  centered at $z$ with radius $2r$ for some $r$ with $0<2r<\frac {1}{m(m+1)}.$ Now $z+r\in U$ but $Re(z+r)+Im(z+r)=\frac 1 m +r\not\in \{\frac 1 n :n\in\Bbb Z^+\}.$ So $U\not\subseteq \cup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+ }X_n.$ So $z\not\in int (\cup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}X_n).$

Comment: Where did the $\frac{1}{m(m+1)}$ come from and why $2r<\frac{1}{m(m+1)}?$

Comment: @JadMON2k1 . $1/m(m+1)$ is the least difference between $1/m$ and the reciprocal of any other natural number. So half of it $(r$) plus $1/m$ cannot be the reciprocal of a natural number.